# Apache sometimes serves the default page rather than redirecting to my app

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a Java web app, and I am using Apache to handle the web traffic, proxying to Tomcat via ajp. System is Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, up-to-date apache, Tomcat 8.5.99 (as of this writing).

The `<VirtualHost *:80>` section of my conf file has a `Redirect` directive to the login URL of my app.

But sometimes, Apache serves up the default /var/www/html/index.html page instead of redirecting when I surf to http://example.com. Sometimes it's after restarting Apache, sometimes not. Sometimes it's after restarting Tomcat, sometimes not.

Refreshing the page always does the redirect correctly, and it works properly thereafter, until I somehow trigger it again.

I have tried `DocumentRoot /opt/tomcat/current/webapps/myapp` but that just gives me a "Index of /" page listing the WEB-INF, META-INF, index.jsp etc.

Note that surfing to https://example.com always does the URL rewrite correctly and ends up on the login page. It's just http:// that fails occasionally.

So...
How do I configure Apache to always do the redirect and never serve up a default page?

Here's my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    #    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    ServerName mydomain.com

    Redirect / https://example.com/myapp/login/login_page

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        # DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RedirectMatch ^/$ https://example.com/myapp/login/login_page
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

        ProxyPass /.well-known !

        ProxyPass /myapp ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp retry=0 timeout=9000
        ProxyPassReverse /myapp ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```